# Cursor does not revert to default in JSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$('#logonButton').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).text() == 'logon') {
        $(this).css('cursor','wait');
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/test?method=logon', function(data, returnValue) {
            $('#output').append("<p>"+data+"</p>");
            $('#logonbutton').css('cursor','default');
            $('#logonButton').text('logoff');
        });
    ...
```

This logon takes some time so I want to set the cursor to 'wait' before the JSON call and then set it back to 'default' when the callback is hit.

The call returns and the data is appended to the output div but the #logonButton div text does not change and the cursor is stuck on 'busy'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `#logonButton`, not `#logonbutton`.

```
$('#logonButton').css('cursor','default');
```

Notice the uppercase `B`.

Also, you should consider reverting the cursor in an [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) handler which will also work in case of an AJAX error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in this line:

```
$('#logonbutton').css('cursor','default');
```

should be

```
$('#logonButton').css('cursor','default');
```